# New folder that is created inside the current directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, operating-system

I have a program in Python that during the processes it creates some files. I want the program to recognize the current directory and then then creates a folder inside the directory, so that the created files will be put in that directory.

I tried this:

```
current_directory = os.getcwd()
final_directory = os.path.join(current_directory, r'/new_folder')
if not os.path.exists(final_directory):
    os.makedirs(final_directory)
```

But it doesn't give me what I wanted. It seems that the second line is not working as I wanted. Can anybody help me to solve the problem?

Comment: *But it doesn't give me what I wanted*: always be explicit in what it did do.

Comment: what is the output of print "<<%s>>" % final_directory  ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One thing to note is that (per the `os.path.join` documentation) if an absolute path is provided as one of the arguments, the other elements are thrown away. For instance (on Linux):

```
In [1]: import os.path

In [2]: os.path.join('first_part', 'second_part')
Out[2]: 'first_part/second_part'

In [3]: os.path.join('first_part', r'/second_part')
Out[3]: '/second_part'
```

And on Windows:

```
>>> import os.path
>>> os.path.join('first_part', 'second_part')
'first_part\\second_part'
>>> os.path.join('first_part', '/second_part')
'/second_part'
```

Since you include a leading `/` in your `join` argument, it is being interpreted as an absolute path and therefore ignoring the rest. Therefore you should remove the `/` from the beginning of the second argument in order to have the join perform as expected. The reason you don't have to include the `/` is because `os.path.join` implicitly uses `os.sep`, ensuring that the proper separator is used (note the difference in the output above for `os.path.join('first_part', 'second_part'`).

Answer (score 39):

think the problem is in `r'/new_folder'` and the slash (refers to the root directory) used in it.

Try it with:

```
current_directory = os.getcwd()
final_directory = os.path.join(current_directory, r'new_folder')
if not os.path.exists(final_directory):
   os.makedirs(final_directory)
```

That should work.

Comment: Look at @RocketDonkey nicer explanation for more information.

Comment: Thank's, you've earned it! :-)

Comment: @hetch what is the use of if statement here?

Comment: @AdnanAkram Its to check if the folder "new_folder" already exists. If it exists, It won't make the dir again