# Write a new folder in current directory and write file to it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following script that will write an input file to a new directory. I would like to change it so I do not have to explicitly tell it what directory it is in to write a new directory. This current approach works fine but requires the user to input the path. I saw the following [New folder that is created inside the current directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14125781/new-folder-that-is-created-inside-the-current-directory) and modified my script in the following way

```
import os

if not os.path.isdir('/home/bkwx97/python/test3/MINP'):
    os.mkdir('/home/bkwx97/python/test3/MINP')


with open('/home/bkwx97/python/test3/MINP/MINP','w') as f:
```

And got the error

> "File "test3backupdir2.py", line 8, in 
>       with open('final_directory/MINP.txt','w') as f: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'final_directory/MINP.txt'"

Am I missing something simple? Or can I not change it so it will write a new folder in the current directory, and write the input there?

```
import os,os.path

current_directory = os.getcwd()
final_directory = os.path.join(current_directory,r'MINP')
if not os.path.exists(final_directory):
   os.makedirs(final_directory)

with open('final_directory/MINP.txt','w') as f:
```

Comment: typo: `with open('final_directory/MINP.txt','w') as f:` should be `with open(os.path.join(final_directory,'MINP.txt'),'w') as f`

Comment: It looks like you are confusing a variable named `final_directory` with the literal string `'final_directory'`.  If you have a variable named `foo`, you can't just write `'foo/bar.txt'` and have the value of the variable expanded.

Comment: Is your working directory the same as the desired input directory? Do you call the script from within the same root dir?

Comment: @albert I do call the script from within the same root dir.

Comment: @bkw: Please copy the script and all other files needed to its own directory and provide both full dir structure and code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you're looking for is:

```
with open('{}/MINP.txt'.format(final_directory),'w') as f:
```