# How can I save pandas dataframe output to a CSV file in a newly created folder?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I save pandas dataframe output to a CSV file in a newly created folder at my project root?

`spaces_df.to_csv(r'CSV_Script_Results/tweepy_spaces.csv', index=False)`

**folder** = CSV_Script_Results  # create this new folder at project root

**file** = tweepy_spaces.csv     # write this file inside ^ folder

The pandas doc isn't clear to me: [Pandas Doc - to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html?highlight=path_or_buf)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [New folder that is created inside the current directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14125781/new-folder-that-is-created-inside-the-current-directory)

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer:

```
import os
os.mkdir('CSV_Script_Results')
spaces_df.to_csv(r'CSV_Script_Results/tweepy_spaces.csv', index=False)
```

I was hoping the solution involved one line instead of importing os, creating a new directory, etc. Not sure why that's the way it is...